# Decoherence time of quarks

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quarks, decoherence

I have been reading papers on using top quark's use as a probe for new physics using quantum information theoretic observables such as concurrence. One of the reasons they provide for using a top quark for this purpose is that its decoherence time is longer than its decay time so its correlations are maintained in daughter particles.

How does one calculate this decoherence time? I searched but came up empty-handed. Please help or point towards relevant literature.

I am quoting from the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.02280.  It is given on the first page third paragraph itself.

Comment: Your ref gives you 19 refs, [32-51], and the go-to ref is, of course, [Mahlon & Parke, 2010](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.81.074024), which leads with $m_t/\Lambda_{QCD}^2\sim 10^{-21}s$, the spin-decorrelation time.

Comment: They don't give a method to calculate it. I want to calculate it for leptons also.

Comment: Oh... are you talking about [this measurement](https://doi.org/10.1140/epjc/s10052-020-8181-6)? The spin decor relation time is effected by QCD flipping spins...

Comment: My guess would be the inverse of the temporal bandwidth, the latter being given by the uncertainty in energy divided by hbar.

Comment: Can you elaborate